# WebLogic server - large file transfers

Tags: weblogic

I may be giving entirely the wrong information here, but at the moment we're a bit unsure where to look for the issue. We have a server running on WebLogic, of which version I'm not sure.

Our site has an installer that clients need that can run around 15 MB. Normally, this downloads perfectly fine, but we've recently been finding issues in the download where the browser reports it completed, but the installer can't be opened - it appears that the filesize isn't what it's expected to be either, like the download was just cut off.
The issues are relegated to instances where the user is on a spotty connection, such as a 3G card in their laptop.

It seems to happen mostly on Macs, but it seems like that's because the mac .dmg file is much larger than the windows executable. Still, from my knowledge of network protocols, a spotty network shouldn't cause the specific issue we're seeing.

At the moment, we're debugging several of the layers of the transfer, like our firewalls, but with my meager knowledge of Weblogic, I'm kind of curious if there is something we could be missing in the server's configuration itself.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure if I am able to post the configuration files here - I'm pretty sure at the moment, there are no servlet rules created specifically for the installer's directory - but I was hoping someone here might at least recognize this type of issue and be able to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have any maxpostsize limit set. 
Check for the responses that has failed if there's any socket timeout errors seen in the log file.
If you are using a proxy, check for error there related mainly to sockets.

Such issues can come when a tcp socket is timed out at the firewall end, WLS end, Frontend proxy like apache end.

There are few other settings like http connection timeout I think in WLS.
check from admin console-server-protocol-general tab or http tab.